# Xpath: Locate a sibling xpath using a fellow sibling xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm having difficulty locating the xpath of an input (checkbox) element that I need to click. I am trying to use a fellow span element to locate it. The elements contain Angular attributes, don't know if that matters?

The elements are structured like this:

```
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="py-1" style="">
  <input _ngcontent-c6="" type="checkbox">
  <span _ngcontent-c6="" class="pl-2">Company name</span>
</div>
```

I am able to locate the span element using this xpath:

```
"//span[text() = '" + SearchInput + "']"
```

But I'm struggling to click on the following input element. This following xpaths do not work for me:

```
"//span[text() = '" + SearchInput + "']/following-sibling::input"
"//span[text() = '" + SearchInput + "']/following-sibling::input[@type = 'checkbox']"
```

I've looked around quite a bit for an answer but I can't seem to find one that works for me. If anyone can help or point me to a question that actually works for me, it'll be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is probably a better way to do it but the following is working for me. Searching a `div` having a child being the `span` and getting the `input` child of that `div`

```
//div[span[text() = 'Company name']]/input
```